# Understanding how contextMenuEvent (or any event in general) works in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Below is the code that generates an empty window that when you right-click it prints "Context menu event!". I'm just wondering (roughly) how this is implemented by PyQt5 because I don't feel comfortable treating it as a complete black box. So I guess here you overwrite `contextMenuEvent` of `QMainWindow` by reducing it to a mere `print` function, but how does this have anything to do with right-clicking? What are the steps that PyQt5 takes from the moment I right-click to when "Context menu event!" is printed?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        print("Context menu event!")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 basically waits for the event to happen, and then after it happend routes it to the object the event is targeted for.

With `app.exec_()` you are starting the Qt event loop. The event loop will wait for events (user input, timers, network traffic, sensors, etc.) in your case that means the mouse click, and after recieving it, it will dispatch the event to the objects that have subscribed to them (in your case your main window). Event loops are a common concept in programming [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop).

You can find the code for the Qt eventloop here: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qeventloop.cpp.html#224